# Interaction quantification in random effects model (varying slopes and intercepts)

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, random-effects-model

[Random effects models with varying slopes and intercepts](http://civil.colorado.edu/%7Ebalajir/CVEN6833/bayes-resources/RM-StatRethink-Bayes.pdf) use a correlations matrix to pool information across slopes and intercepts. I recall hearing that this matrix is a powerful tool for understanding interactions between variables. But I'm struggling to understand how this might be the case. Say, you estimate the covariance or correlation between two variables to be high, how would this help you understand that they interact in a meaningful way?

For example, say that you measure people's motor skills when given alcohol, opiates or both. It's known that these chemicals have a stronger effect on motor skills together than in isolation. But would a random effects model with varying slopes and intercepts be able to quantify that? How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance matrix of the random effects can be used to understand the correlation between them, but not for the fixed effects.

In your example, the interaction happens in the fixed effects and the covariance matrix of the random effects does not give any information about it.

Let us admit that in your example, we sampled the motor skill of the same participants multiple times. We can then add and random intercept and also add a random slope for the variable opiates consumption. Let us imagine that the fixed coefficient for this variable is negative (opiates reduce motor skill). If the two random effects are positively correlated (in the covariance matrix of the random effects), it means that individuals with a "higher random intercept" also tend to have a "higher random slope". Here it would mean that participants with good motor skill tend to be less affected by opiates (a positive random slope is added to the negative coefficient).

Comment: For clarification, the fixed effect is at the aggregate level and the random effect is at the individual/subgroup level, right?

Comment: The fixed effect is at the observation unit level and the random effects are at the grouping levels.